# Find matches from an index file without exact matching and print the last field

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, gawk

I have a large file (~6mill rows) with 2 columns which looks like this:

```
1111.aaaaabbb.b.cccc.c  ValueA
2222.dddddeee.e.ffff.f  ValueB
3333.gggghhhh.h.iiii.i  ValueC
```

I want to use that as my index when searching this single column file:

```
aaaaabbb.b  
dddddeee.e  
gggghhhh.h
```

And return:

```
ValueA
ValueB
ValueC
[...]
Valuen
```

As you can see I just care about the value after the first period, as long as there's an exact match of the contents of the second file to the first file (not exact) I want it to return the value of column 2 from the first file. I don't care about the prefix/suffix of the first file's contents as long as the exact content of file 2 matches up.

Is there any way to do this with `awk` or any `bash` tool? Currently I'm trying to format the data properly in Excel (data to column tool) but it's taking a long, long time as I have well over 6million rows so I have to manually do 6 files, and then compile the results together.

**Edit** on `file1` contents: The prefix is always numerical, but varies in length from 4 to 7 digits. The content after the first period is alphanumeric and varies in length from 4 to 15 characters and can begin with numbers or letters, and the suffix is numbers/alphabets as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the file with the index is not too huge, that it can be loaded completely into memory. If yes, you can use this `awk`:

```
awk -F"[. ]" 'FNR==NR{a[$0]=1} FNR!=NR&&a[$2"."$3]{print $NF}' index_file huge_file
```

---

- `awk` is called with two files: `index_file` with the contents to search for and `huge_file` with many row as in the question.
- `-F"[. ]"` set awks delimiter to space and dot.
- `FNR==NR` applies only to `index_file`

  - `a[$0]=1` fill an array `a` with the search patterns as indexes and set the value to `1`, just that the array is built.
- `FNR!=NR` applies only to the `huge_file`.
- `a[$2"."$3]` if the array index of field 2 and field 3 concatenated by a dot exist (when the pattern is found)...

  - `print $NF` print the last field of the file.

---

The output:

```
ValueA
ValueB
ValueC
```